# Turn int list into int

Tags: ocaml

For example, if I have [1;2;3] I want to output int 123. There's flatten functions but they're for int list list -> int list, or a variation of that. Is what I'm looking to do possible?

Comment: Of course its possible. But SO is not made for people to do your work for you. Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Apologies - didn't realize stack overflow was only for pro programmers asking high-complexity questions /s. Of course I tried on my own before asking SO. Posting anything below senior dev level questions guarantees downvotes, so I avoid posting here as much as I can.

Comment: Honestly, its true. Even I try not to post questions on here. But this site is mainly for questions with the language, not "how to do this specific thing." I'm not sure what site will help you with those kinds of questions, but not this one. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. Try this:

```
let by_digits = List.fold_left (fun acc digit -> acc * 10 + digit) 0
```

---

```
by_digits [1; 2; 3];;
- : int = 123
```

Of course, this assumes your list items are in the range 0-9.

Comment: Wow, that seems so obvious in retrospect. Thank you!